# Magento2 Invoice cannot be saved

Tags: magento2

I just did a test order on my magento 2.0.0 store. 
By creating a invoice for the PO order, i get the error "We can't save the invoice right now."

After testing and trying, i viewed the exception.log file which states the following:

```
Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'base_grand_total' in 'field list', query was: IN$
 LEFT JOIN `dxm2_sales_order` AS `sales_order` ON sales_invoice.order_id = sales_order.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `dxm2_sales_order_address` AS `sales_shipping_address` ON sales_invoice.shipping_address_id = sales_shipping_address.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `dxm2_sales_order_address` AS `sales_billing_address` ON sales_invoice.billing_address_id = sales_billing_address.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `dxm2_sales_order_payment` AS `sales_order_payment` ON sales_invoice.order_id = sales_order_payment.parent_id WHERE (sales_invo$
```

should base_grand_total not have the prefix?

Its magento2 2.0.0. in developer mode. just did a transaction for first time.

Comment: This is a common bug. **That column dosn't exist into your database**.

Run the following SQL into your database:
__ALTER TABLE `sales_invoice_grid`
    ADD COLUMN `base_grand_total` DECIMAL(12,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Grand Total' AFTER `grand_total`;__

Find solutions [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5546) and [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5324). Links are to magento 2 Git issues.

Answer (score 1):

1. base_grand_total was added to Magento\Sales\Setup\InstallSchema after Magento2 was released.
2. InstallSchema files are not run when upgrading Magento
3. People installing Magento from scratch today will have base_grand_total in sales_invoice_grid, but people who upgraded Magento from lower versions will not.

**HERE IS SOLUTION**

1. Given that base_grand_total is an upgrade to the Schema, it should be in Magento\Sales\Setup\UpgradeSchema so that people upgrading can get it.
2. In general InstallSchema files should never be edited once included in a release.
3. You can directly add column in sales_invoice_grid table to check this solution is working for you or not.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `sales_invoice_grid` ADD `BASE_GRAND_TOTAL` VARCHAR(220) NOT NULL AFTER `updated_at`;
   ```

**[REFERENCE](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5546)**